# Integrate Classroom with a web game

Tags: google-classroom

I would like to integrate (if possible) my web puzzle game (I'm a Puzzle) with Google Classroom.

At I'm a Puzzle (https://im-a-puzzle.com) one can create jigsaw-like puzzle games from any picture. All you need to do is select a picture, mode and difficulty and press share. Once done, the picture is uploaded to my server and the user gets an unique link to his puzzle game that he can share in any social media.

Some teachers are already sharing the created links in Google Classroom, but they would like to have a better integration.

The integration could work as follows.

1. Teacher enters the game, configures a puzzle, gets an unique link for his/her game (as of today)
2. Teacher shares the puzzle link with the students via Google Classroom (I understand this is possible via the share button)
3. Student click the link in Google Classroom and plays the game. At this point I must be able to identify which student (id?) is playing
4. When the student finishes the game, my web app communicates all the game info (student, score, time, etc.) back to the teacher via Google Classroom

Is this all possible? I couldn't find anything like this in the guides (apart from the share button).

Comment: `Teacher creates a game` this is very broad. How is this being created?

Comment: I edited it. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: It is absolutely no clearer at all. What are you talking about? A flash game? Some Google form you're calling a game? A Javascript-built pong? Pokémon Red served by en emulator embedded in a web page? How is it passing any information from anywhere? How do you get information from it? Please provide as much information as you can because this is still too broad to even be considered answerable.

Comment: Hi Rafa, I put more information now. I was hesitating to do it, because I don't it to look like self promotion, which I know is not allowed at stackoverflow.

Comment: You might be able to set up passing the student name to your web app but you'll need to set that up server-side. When you say `When the student finishes the game, my web app communicates all the game info back to the teacher via Google Classroom`, how exactly do you mean? To what part of Classroom are you wanting this information passed?

Comment: How can I instruct classroom to pass the student name in the url? Regarding the second question, it can be done in the front ent or backend (whatever is possible). I want to pass this information so that the teacher can see who played the game and what was the score.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You'd have to have an individual link for each student to click with their respective URL parameters, Classroom itself can't send information like that out. Can you not prompt your students to enter their name on the game side before passing it back?

Comment: I could. But then how do I send the information back? What if the student mistype his name?

I was wondering if (and how) I could make the game an assignment.

Comment: If the student mistypes their name... well then yeah they're screwed. I would suggest implementing Google OAuth on your website with Drive and Classroom scopes so you can get the student name, info, Drive etc, then create the coursework submission with [the turnin API method](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/turnIn). But this is now reaching outside of the scope of stackoverflow, once you've tried some implementation and get stuck I'd suggest posting a new question about the specifics of where you're stuck.